# Extracting common data within a table without Dynamic Query OR Intersect

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following `Vehicle` Table:

[image]

from which I want the vehicle id/names with every `Index` value, i.e. the following result

[image]

I have made a dynamic query which can produce this result:

```
select vehicleId,vehicleName from Vehicle where [Index] = 1
intersect
select vehicleId,vehicleName from Vehicle where [Index] = 2
intersect
select vehicleId,vehicleName from Vehicle where [Index] = 3
```

but I cannot use a dynamic query with all possible `Index` values.

I need a solution which involves self join or some non-dynamic SQL techniques to perform the same. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `group by` to find `vehicleId, vehicleName` combinations with every `index`:

```
select vehicleId, vehicleName
from Vehicle
group by vehicleId, vehicleName
having count(distinct [index]) = (select count(distinct [Index]) from Vehicle)
```

Comment: count(distinct [index]) > 1 gives both all since Honda and Suzuki since they occur twice. It should be "having count(distinct [IndexId]) = MAX(indexid)". Kindly update your answer and I will accept it. :)

Comment: Note that `max(index)` is not safe since there may be gaps in index numbers

Comment: Eventhough in my case that won't happen, this is a much more practical and generic solution. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is clearer with a CTE?

```
WITH I_LIST AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT Index
  FROM Vehicle
)
SELECT V.VehicleId, V.VehicleName
FROM I_LIST
LEFT JOIN Vehicle V ON I_List.Index = V.Index
GROUP BY V.VehicleId, V.VehicleName
HAVING COUNT(I_List.Index) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM I_LIST)
```